# OpenGL diffuse light

Tags: opengl, glsl, lighting

I met some problems when implementing diffuse light.
correct result may look like the picture on left [diffuse light picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBdpK.png)
The right side is incorrect result.
The problems are below
1.There is no lighting effect in the beginning.I have to rotate the object to some degree the lighting effect will appear.
2.The object mixed some triangle in it. (I have checked my read file(.obj &.mtl) part already. It's correct.)
3.I only turn on the diffuse light. But the lighting effect seems to ambient light.
My light source position is (0, 0, 5), eye position is(0, 0, 0);

my vertex shader

```
attribute vec4 vertexPosition;
attribute vec3 vertexNormal_objectSpace;

varying vec4 vv4color;

uniform mat4 mvp; //model, viewing, projection transformation matrix
uniform mat4 NormalMatrix;

struct LightSourceParameters 
{
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    vec4 position;
    vec4 halfVector;
    vec3 spotDirection;
    float spotExponent;
    float spotCutoff; // (range: [0.0,90.0], 180.0)
    float spotCosCutoff; // (range: [1.0,0.0],-1.0)
    float constantAttenuation;
    float linearAttenuation;
    float quadraticAttenuation;
};

struct MaterialParameters 
{
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    float shininess;
};

uniform MaterialParameters Material;
uniform LightSourceParameters LightSource[3]; //because I have to implement three light sources(directional, point, specular light)  

void main() 
{
    vec3 normal, TransformedNormal, lightDirection;
    vec4 ambient, diffuse;                                      
    float NdotL;

    ambient = LightSource[0].ambient * Material.ambient;            
    TransformedNormal = vec3(vec4(vertexNormal_objectSpace, 0.0) * NormalMatrix);
    normal = normalize(TransformedNormal);                  
    lightDirection = normalize(vec3(LightSource[0].position));
    NdotL = max(dot(normal, lightDirection), 0.0);              
    diffuse = LightSource[0].diffuse * Material.diffuse * NdotL;    

    vv4color = ambient + diffuse; //vv4color pass to fragment shader
    gl_Position = mvp * vertexPosition;
}
```

my display function

```
void onDisplay(void)
{
    Matrix4 MVP, modelView, NormalMatrix;
    int i=0;

    // clear canvas
    glClearColor(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);   
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(iLocPosition);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(iLocNormal);

    geo_rotate = geo_rotate_x * geo_rotate_y * geo_rotate_z;
    Geo = geo_rotate * geo_scale * geo_trans;

    modelView = View * Geo; 
    modelView = modelView.transpose();  //row-major -> column-major 
    modelView = modelView.invert();     //normal transformation(transpose after inverse)
    NormalMatrix = modelView.transpose();

    MVP = Proj * View * Geo * Norm;
    MVP = MVP.transpose();  

    glUniformMatrix3fv(iLocEyePosition, 1, GL_FALSE, &eye[0]);  
    glUniformMatrix4fv(iLocNormalMatrix, 1, GL_FALSE, &NormalMatrix[0]);    //bind uniform matrix to shader
    glUniformMatrix4fv(iLocMVP, 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0]);

    group = OBJ->groups;
    for(i=0; i<OBJ->numgroups-1; i++)
    {
        //pass model material value to the shader
        glUniform4fv(iLocMAmbient, 1, material[i].ambient);
        glUniform4fv(iLocMDiffuse, 1, material[i].diffuse);
        glUniform4fv(iLocMSpecular, 1, material[i].specular);   
        glUniform1f(iLocMShininess, material[i].shininess);

        glVertexAttribPointer(iLocPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, V[i]);    //bind array pointers to shader
        glVertexAttribPointer(iLocNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, N[i]);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, group->numtriangles*3);                   //draw the array we just bound

        group = group->next;
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Thank you all of you.

Comment: What space is are your light source positions in? Why do you _post_ multiply `NormalMatrix` to a vector while you _pre_ multiply `mvp`? Seems like you are not consistent with your conventions here.

Comment: My light source space is world space. normal_vector * inverse(NormalMatrix) is the same as inverse(transpose(NormalMatrix)) * normal_vector. I use pre multiply NormalMatrix originally, but I use post multiply later. I forgot to revise the comment,sorry. I found the answer already. The problem is the normal variable name in my main.c and vertex shader isn't the same. So, the result don't have normal informations. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Not quite, `v * inverse(M)` is the same as `transpose(inverse(M)) * v`, not `v*inverse(transpose(M))`. You just might not notice the difference because the normal matrix might be orthogonal. Apart from that, your calculations are still not really making sense. Your `lightDirection` is in world space, while `normal` has been transformed to eye space. Furthermore, `lightDirection` seems to assume the that shaded point is at world space center (or that you are using a directional light), since you are not taking the actual coordinates of the point into account.

Comment: I make a mistake in the order. You're right. v * inverse(M) is the same as transpose(inverse(M)). And, I didn't notice the lightDirection and the normal space. I will take that into account. Thank you for your notice.